# Terraform 12 - multiple lines

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

In terraform 11, this syntax has no issues:

```
tags = "${
    merge(
      map("Name", format("%s-%s-%s",var.environment_name,"WAN","RouteTable")), 
      var.tags_module,
      var.tags_global
    )
  }"
```

In terraform 12, i have to remove brackets `{}` and need to put all in one line to get this working:

```
tags = merge(map("Name", format("%s-%s-%s",var.environment_name,"WAN","RouteTable")), var.tags_module, var.tags_global)
```

However, if i split above statement into multiple lines:

```
tags = 
merge(
map("Name", format("%s-%s-%s",var.environment_name,"WAN","RouteTable")),
var.tags_module,
var.tags_global
)
```

I'm getting following error:

```
Expected an attribute value, introduced
by an equals sign ("=").
```

Is there a way to use multi-lines in terraform 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valid syntax for HCL2 would be the following:

```
tags = merge(
  map("Name", format("%s-%s-%s",var.environment_name,"WAN","RouteTable")),
  var.tags_module,
  var.tags_global,
)
```